# Simulator application using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm developing an application for Freight purposes. I want to add a cargo container loading simulator to the application to optimize the container loading, so the user can load cartons into the container manually like a 3D puzzle game. Carton dimensions and container dimensions comes from a database table.

What is the suitable software or add-on to be used to build this kind of simulator?

Comment: Your question is broad and difficult to answer. Are you asking about how to interface with the database to retrieve carton/container dimensions? Are you asking what programming language to write the application in? Are you asking whether there are any existing libraries or frameworks to help you build your application more quickly? Please provide more details, someone is sure to be able to help with enough information.

Comment: I have a parent table contains a cargo container  dimensions and a child table contains Several cartons with several dimensions  i want to create a graphic that contains both cargo container and cartons and be able to(drag and drop) cartons into the container. so I'm asking what kind of applications or controls to be used to achieve that.      thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that this question has a *visual-studio-lightswitch* tag, so I'll reply to that aspect.

You would need to create a *custom Silverlight control* to graphically display the information as you describe. There's no LS built-in control that would do that. So you'd need some working knowledge of Silverlight (which LS currently uses as its presentation technology - HTML 5 support is being currently developed by the LS team).

As for the rest of the application, the answer to "could it be done in LS" is "probably". LS is **great** for "forms over data" type applications. But it can also be extended (with the custom Silverlight controls I mentioned earlier).